# Установить шрифт для контрола.

Tags: winapi

Хочу установить шрифт для определенного контрола, но возникла проблемы с HFONT. При отправке сообщения таким образом:

> SendMessage(target, WM_SETFONT, NULL,
> true);

устанавливает стандартный шрифт системы, а я хочу установить любой другой. Для этого нужен HFONT искомого шрифта, но как его получить? Пробовал CreateFont(), но возникла ошибка:

> [Linker error] undefined reference to
> `CreateFontA@56'

Хотя я думаю, что это не совсем то, что нужно. Должен быть способ сделать это проще.

Comment: >[Linker error] undefined reference to `CreateFontA@56'

[Library: Use Gdi32.lib.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183499(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Пробовал подключить Gdi32.lib с помощью #pragma comment - не выходит. Оказалось, что #pragma comment работает не для всех компиляторов.